# Иконки не отображаются font awesome

Tags: html, fontawesome

Хочу подключить иконки на сайт подключил кит font awesome, но иконки не отображаются. Подскажите что делать?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/0cc6b2c2f1.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin-in"></i>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Версия вашего font-awesome не сама последняя, судя по всему. Поэтому используйте другую нотацию:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/0cc6b2c2f1.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i>
  </body>
</html>
```